# How to make a duplicate file or copy the contents of stdout file to a new file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following way to capture the output of the python script in a file:

```
class Logger(object):
        def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
                self.terminal = sys.stdout
                self.log = open(filename, "w")

        def write(self, message):
                self.terminal.write(message)
                self.log.write(message)

        def flush(self):
                pass

sys.stdout = Logger("logfile.log")
```

After the output is logged in a file I am then using using the following method to read from the logfile to write its contents to another file

```
def read_file():
        count = 0
        with open('logfile.log', 'r') as firstfile, open('file.txt', 'a') as secondfile:
                for line in firstfile:
                        secondfile.write(line)
```

The problem I am facing is the output of the log file keeps getting refreshed whenever I try to capture the output. How can I create a duplicate file as I want to search for a string and print its occurrences.

Comment: Maybe you'd  be better off using a database of some sort, because the file will be refreshed as soon as you write to it, that is one of the reasons why databases are used instead of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue I had to open the file and the file mode as **r+**. So it would be:

```
class Logger(object):
        def __init__(self, filename="Default.log"):
                self.terminal = sys.stdout
                **self.log = open(filename, "r+")**

        def write(self, message):
                self.terminal.write(message)
                self.log.write(message)

        def flush(self):
                pass

sys.stdout = Logger("logfile.log")
```